# Table-valued function - duplicate table declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using table-valued function in SQL Server to return data either with ties or without on some condition specified.

Now the solution works fine but I do not like the fact that I have to declare the table twice - is there any workaroud? I could probably instead of inserting into `@tmp` table use `@ReturnTable` but that data would have to be deleted once `select top 1` is queried at the end of the function.

```
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE
    (
    idTable   INT,
    idOther   INT,
    name      VARCHAR(30)
    )
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @tmp TABLE
            (   
            idTable         INT,
            idOther         INT,
            name            VARCHAR(30)
            )

         INSERT INTO @tmp
                SELECT idTable,
                       idOther,       
                       name
                FROM SomeTable

         IF (some condition)
             BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                        SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES idTable,
                                               idOther,       
                                               name
                        FROM @tmp
                        ORDER BY (some ordering)
             END;
         ELSE
             BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
                        SELECT TOP 1 idTable,
                                     idOther,       
                                     name
                        FROM @tmp
                        ORDER BY (some other ordering)
             END;
         RETURN;
     END;
```

Comment: `TOP` without `Order By` does not make lot of sense

Comment: There is an order by, let me correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-writing your function to `Inline table valued function`.

Based on the condition you have to use either `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` window function. `TOP 1 with TIES` can be achieved using `DENSE_RANK/RANK`

```
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN 
      (SELECT idtable, 
              idother, 
              NAME 
       FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN (some condition) THEN Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY (some ordering)) 
                        ELSE Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (some other ordering)) 
                      END     AS RN, 
                      idtable,
                      idOther, 
                      NAME 
               FROM   sometable)a 
       WHERE  RN = 1)
```